# How to randomize a picture box within a certain area

Tags: vb.net

So,I am trying to make a game that is based on collecting items to earn points and the objective is to always try and beat your high score. I have make it so the crate randomises at a random position anywhere on the form, I have a background of a city in my form, so I now want it to randomise only on the roads instead of anywhere on the form, I have also created a picture box for each of the roads and had put it into an array,but I don't know if that would be of any use, so i am kinda stuck now. Can anyone help me with this problem?
Thx

Comment: Welcome to [so].  Try to make your stuff step by step, and check [ask] and provide [mcve] if you encounter specific problem.

Comment: Show us what you got, Detailed Question and what you tried so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one works but try it first on a seperate program and 
after you try it. You will be given a chance on how you will
do the randomize on your own.

1. Create a program
2. Add a new form (Form1)
3. Add a picturebox and a button
4. Import your moms picture inside the picturebox (Remember : it will not work if you dont do it XD)
5. Inside your form add this piece of code:

   ```
   Public Class Form1

       Dim RandomClass As New Random()
       Dim Y As Integer

       Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
           PictureBox1.Show()
       End Sub

       Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
           For pos = 1 To 100
               Y = RandomClass.Next(300)
               PictureBox1.Location = New Point(100, Y)
           Next pos
       End Sub

   End Class
   ```

The output of that is

The maximum location of the picture of your mother will be at the max of 300 with random location between 0 to 300 just adjust anywhere you want.

Thats all :)

Comment: What if i want to pick a road at random from my array and randomise it anywhere on that road/picturebox, will it work then?

Comment: yes definitely, as what you see on code the X,Y Location is adjustable. you can set it anywhere you love.